# gnuplot license compatibility

Tags: licensing

I have a Python software package *Foobar* that, amongst other things, uses [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) for displaying graphs on the command line. [The gnuplot license is open-source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnuplot#Distribution_terms), [but not compatible with the GPL,](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html#gnuplot) so if I were to license *Foobar* under the GPL, nobody could legally use it. Is this correct?

What licenses is the gnuplot license compatible with?

Comment: How does your package invoke gnuplot functionality?

Comment: It creates a config string, then calls the `gnuplot` command line program with that string as input, and fetches the output.